# Is the addtoken parameter in the location function(cflocation tag) a boolean?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I'm using CF9.

The function [cflocation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cac.html) has a parameter

```
addToken = "yes|no"
```

It is not mentioned if this is actually a boolean, e.g. are the following two equivalent?

```
<cflocation url = "http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm" addToken = "no">
<cflocation url = "http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm" addToken = "false">
```

When calling this method in `cfscript` using the function
[Location](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS5EFF891F-C93E-43a7-8082-39253F3EF107.html) can I pass a `boolean` as a parameter?

```
<cfscript>
   location(url="http://localhost:8500/administrator", addtoken = false);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they are the same and yes you can pass them in cfscript as a parameter. You can even use 0 and 1.

For false:

```
<cflocation url = "http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm" addToken = "no">
<cflocation url = "http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm" addToken = "false">
<cflocation url = "http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm" addToken = "0">
<cfscript>location(url="http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm", addtoken = false);</cfscript>
<cfscript>location(url="http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm", addtoken = "no");</cfscript>
<cfscript>location(url="http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm", addtoken = 0);</cfscript>
```

For true:

```
<cflocation url = "http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm" addToken = "yes">
<cflocation url = "http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm" addToken = "true">
<cflocation url = "http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm" addToken = "1">
<cfscript>location(url="http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm", addtoken = true);</cfscript>
<cfscript>location(http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm", addtoken = "yes");</cfscript>
<cfscript>location(url="http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm", addtoken = 1);</cfscript>
```

BTW you could easily verify this you self by creating a small sample file and test it.

Comment: I've no idea how to test if the `addtoken` parameter is behaving as expected.

Comment: @Roland The tokens are (or are not) displayed in your browser as parameters. Something like ?CFID=xxxxx&CFTOKEN=xxxxx. So if you create a test page which uses cflocation to redirect you, you either see the tokens as paramters in your browsers url bar or you do not.